# Predict number of employees for upcoming months

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet with columns for the start and end dates of employees in a project. Like:

```
Name (Cell A1)    Start Date(Cell B1)     End Date(Cell C1)
John Doe (A2)     9/1/2015 (B2)           3/1/2016 (C2)
D Barret (A2)     8/1/2015 (B2)           2/1/2016 (C2)
D Barret (A2)     7/1/2015 (B2)           8/1/2015 (C2)
```

Based on these start and end dates, I want to count the number of resources in the next months:

```
Month (F1)    #Employees (G1)
Jan 2016          2
Feb 2016          3
```

I want to autopopulate the `#Employees` column with numbers based on the start and end dates. So if there are three people who start/continue in February of 2016, then I will have those three minus the people who leave in January.

What would be the best way of achieving this in Excel?

Comment: are you wishing to base the result in `G1` based on the end / start dates in columns `B:C` or do you want to add / subtract the `G1` amount by the end/start dates in columns `B:C`? Or something different?

Comment: I don't get how your example shows 2 for Jan and 3 for Feb. Can you explain that a bit more?

Comment: @JohnBustos The 2 and 3 are just placeholders not real calulated numbers ..

Comment: @ScottHoltzman your first option is what I am looking for. Having the column G filled out based on B:C

Comment: Yes, your example placeholders were confusing me too, because the real output based on your data was different. You have your answer below. That is the same answer I would have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the formula in cell B9 below.  I am a little confused on exactly what you are asking for.  The below function will count the amount of employees that are currently working in January 2016.  So essentially the Jan 2016 has to be between the employees start date and end date.

[image]